# Alternative for reduceSum in crossfilter and dc

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a dataset of the following kind:

```
a:5 b:4 c:3 d:A
a:6 b:5 c:4 d:A
a:7 b:6 c:5 d:B
a:8 b:7 c:6 d:B
a:9 b:8 c:7 d:C
```

I wanted 'd' to be the dimension for my crossfilter and the value to be plotted in the graph is (a/b) from the dataset. For doing this, I added an extra field in my dataset called 'e'=(a/b) and then passed it as an i/p to crossfilter in the following way:

```
var facts = crossfilter(json); // json being the name of my dataset
var pfmValue = facts.dimension(function(d) {return d.d;});
var pfmValueGroupSum = pfmValue.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.e;});
```

Then I plotted a dc chart using pfmValue as dimension and pfmValueGroupSum along the Y-axis of the bar chart.But now I realise that this is not what I wanted to plot.Now, i have three bars showing values equal to following expression:

```
bar A: (5/4)+(6/5)
bar B: (7/6)+(8/7)
bar C: (9/8)
```

However what I wanted is:

```
bar A: (5+6)/(4+5)
bar B: (7+8)/(6+7)
bar C: (9/8)
```

How do I do it??Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to create a custom grouping that tracks the sum of "a" and the sum of "b" in separate properties. Then you can figure "sum a"/"sum b" when you build your visualization.

Comment: How can a custom grouping of this kind be done?? Can you give links to a few examples??

Comment: There's an example here: https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_order  The ordering part is probably irrelevant to you, but it tracks both a count and a total.

Comment: It almost worked but I am having an issue. Am I going wrong somewhere???Please, have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180398/dc-cross-filter-not-working

Comment: please take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25483757/disable-filtering-on-click-for-second-series-in-composite-chart-in-dc-js